# Background color not working JPanel inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to do a very simple thing.. set the background color on the JPanel inside my JFrame. I have not used `swing` very much so I am still learning. However, I have read up on doing something as basic as setting the background color quite a bit, and I do not know why what I have is not working.

I have my `JFrame` set up in my `Main` class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private static Screen screen;
    private static int WIDTH = 600;
    private static int HEIGHT = 600;

    public Main() {
        screen = new Screen();
        setTitle("Asteroid");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(screen, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

And then I have my `JPanel` set up in a `Screen` class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Screen extends JPanel {
    private static int WIDTH = 600;
    private static int HEIGHT = 600;
    private Dimension screen = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    public Screen() {
        setSize(screen);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setOpaque(true);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why this is not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you `@Override` `paint` method (you should not) of your `JFrame`. In addition you leave it empty, without calling the `super` paint method. So, if you simply add `super.paint(g);` to your `@Override` you will see that background is painted without problems.

However, when you want to do custom painting, you should `@Override` `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, and again, start by calling `super.paintComponent(g);`.